# Student Locker puzzle

Tags: c, puzzle

/* There are 100 students and 100 lockers. Student 1 opens all, student 2 closes every second one, student 3 changes every third
locker(closes if open, opens if close), Student 4 changes every forth locker and so on for all 100 students.
Which locker will be left open? */

Here is my code thus far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
int locker[100], i, closed = 0, opened = 0;

for(i=0; i<100; i++) locker[i] = 1;//0 means closed locker, 1 means open locker
for(i=1; i<101; i++) if(i % 2 == 0) locker[i-1] = 0; // every second locker is closed by second student...(2,4,6,7)
for(i=3; i<101; i++){ // i means student no. i
    if(locker[i-1] == 0) locker[i-1] = 1;
    if(locker[i-1] == 1) locker[i-1] = 0;
```

***if I substitute "if(locker[i-1] == 1)" with "else" why the program doesn't work? Correct result is opened 1 closed 99. If I use 'else' result becomes opened 50 and closed 50***

```
}
for(i=0; i<100; i++){
    if(locker[i] == 0) closed = closed + 1;
    else opened = opened + 1;
}
printf("opened locker %d\nclosed locker %d", opened, closed);
return 0;
```

}

This is my first post in stack overflow. Correct me if I've done anything wrong.

Comment: Without the else you get the wrong result, not with the else.

Comment: Evaluate the conditions by hand and then start thinking. That is not even related to a speific programming language, but can be reproduced in normal english language.

Comment: I just wanted to write a code. Started learning recently. Thank you

Comment: I added the point that you can use `locker[i-1] ^= 1` instead of the if

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give you a few hints to help you out.

- The answer is that 10 lockers remain open, 90 are closed.
- For this particular problem, it's easier to write the code if you avoid zero-based indexing. So
  declare the array as `int locker[101];` and then use indexes 1 thru
  100 to represent the 100 lockers.
- The Nth student is supposed to change every Nth locker. So you need
  two nested `for` loops. The outer loop keeps track of `n`, and the
  inner loop flips lockers.
- The inner loop that only affects every Nth locker should look like
  this

  ```
  for ( i = n; i <= 100; i += n ) // every Nth locker
      locker[i] = 1 - locker[i];  // flip the locker
  ```

  Note that instead of the normal `i=0` and `i++`, we have `i=n`
  and `i+=n`. So, for example, if `n` is 3, then the values of `i`
  are `3,6,9,...`

Comment: thanks I was miss lead.
wrong ans [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c0yQsfcu4b0)
right ans [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c18GjbnZXMw)

Answer (score 0):

Though I have not checked entire code and the logic of your question is not very clear to me, these lines seem to be problematic in your code:

```
if(locker[i-1] == 0) locker[i-1] = 1;
if(locker[i-1] == 1) locker[i-1] = 0;
```

What you're doing here is if a value is 0, then you are setting it to 1, then you are checking again, if it is 1, you are setting it to 0. So, so in this case all values will be set to 0 after running through both these statements.

Instead you should be doing

```
if(locker[i-1] == 0) locker[i-1] = 1;
else locker[i-1] = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that your loop is wrong because you are looping over every locker for the third student and not looping over the remainder. You should for each student (n) change every nth locker to the reverse.

Also when you have the two ifs in a row. If the first if opens a locker, the second if sees it open and closes it (which is wrong). The else is required to actually change it.

Another point is that you can use exclusive or instead of the if `locker[i] ^= 1`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
int locker[100], i, k, closed = 0, opened = 0;

for(i=0; i<100; i++) {
  if (i%2 == 0) locker[i] = 1; // odd lockers (base 1) stay open
  else locker[i] = 0; // even lockers (base 1) are closed
  //0 means closed locker, 1 means open locker
  for(i=3; i<101; i++){ // i means student no. i
    for (k=i; k<101); k+=i) { // change every ith locker
      // if (locker[k-1] == 0) locker[k-1]=1
      // else locker[i-1] = 0;
      // use exclusive or instead of if
      locker[i-1] ^= 1;
    }
   }
}
// Now check the number open or closed
for(i=0; i<100; i++){
    if(locker[i] == 0) closed = closed + 1;
    else opened = opened + 1;
}
printf("opened locker %d\nclosed locker %d", opened, closed);
return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

LOCKERS is the new FIZZBUZZ.

Here's a version which uses Booleans.

```
/* locker problem.c

*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main (void)
{
    bool locker[101];           // locker open = true, closed = false

    // student 1 opens all lockers
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; ++i) {
        locker[i] = true;
    }

    // subsequent students toggle (flip) subsequent lockers
    for (int i = 2; i <= 100; ++i) {
        for (int j = i; j <= 100; j += i) {
            locker[j] = ! locker[j];
        }
    }

    // display results
    printf("\nopen lockers:");
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; ++i) {
        if (locker[i]) {
            printf(" %d", i);
        }
    }
    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

At the conclusion of the process the open lockers are the ones with a number which is a perfect square -- a perfect square has an odd number of divisors.

Answer (score 0):

solution without using an array.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

int studentTotal , lockerTotal,  visit, totalOpened = 0, totalClosed = 0;


cout << "Enter number of students" << endl;
cin >> studentTotal;



lockerTotal = studentTotal;

    for (int locker = 1; locker <= lockerTotal;  locker++ ){ // locker loop
        cout << "\n\n\nLocker no." << locker << endl;
        cout << " is visited by student(s) ";
        visit = 0;
        for (int student = 1 ; student <= studentTotal; student++) { // student loop

        if( locker % student == 0) {
                cout << student << ", ";
                visit++;}

        }//end of locker loop

        cout << "\nTotal number of visits: " << visit;
        if (visit % 2 == 0){
            cout << " the locker will stay closed.";
            totalClosed++;}
        else { cout << " the locker will be opened.";
            totalOpened++;}

    } //end of student loop

    if (lockerTotal == totalOpened + totalClosed) {
        cout << "\n\n\nOf total lockers (" << lockerTotal << "), " << totalOpened << " will be left open." << "(" << totalClosed << ") " << "will be closed." << endl;
        }else cout << "Error!!";



    return 0;

}
```